# How to set grails proxy have error & grails install

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

i want to know error grails can you help me

```js
|Loading Grails 2.4.0
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 2, the proxy is configured and set in a file that (I believe) is in your ~/.grails directory.  There are command-line arguments for setting that documented in the grails documentation here: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.2/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html

In general you would do something like

```
grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=4300 --username=guest --password=guest
```

And then activate it like

```
grails set-proxy client
```

Comment: thank you. sorry can you help me? how i add-proxy and i don't know where proxy

Comment: You add a proxy by using a command like the ones I included in my answer.  I don't know what your proxy server would be.  If you don't know either, then you probably don't need a proxy server at all.